How do i create polylines in an Autocad 2007 DXF using C#?
How do I create some polylines with vertices in a custom AutoCAD 2007 DXF using C# code? I want to create a DXF for laser marker software to import.

2d or 3d? And 2d have different flavours of polyline.

Here is some crude C# that worked for me. It requires a considerably massive 19KB header file to be copied to the destination file, then the footer file is appended to that.
It generates a hex value under the "5" header attribute for each polyline. This is because it needs a unique identifier per polyline.
I was able to write 1044 polys, 99702 vertices without a hitch. The biggest trouble is the header and I haven't tried hard to simplify it so is around 2650 lines. The footer is 34 lines.
As I can't upload the header and footer, you will need to create them. I used LibreCAD to create a Basic Autocad 2007 DXF and drew a non-closed Polyline with a few points. Using Notepad++ I searched for LWPOLYLINE in the file to find the line position where i could determine the end of the header file just before the start of "0" and "LWPOLYLINE" to create as the DXF_header.txt file and i could then make the DXF_footer.txt file from beneath the last Y vertice coordinate of the polyline.
In your text editor save everything from

and make this DXF_header.txt
The footer file looks like this

Make sure to leave a new line at the end of the header file and in the footer file too. Code is as below.
        public void WriteDXF(int num_rows)
        {
            string sourceheaderFile = @"c:\DDMG\DXF_header.txt";
            string sourcefooterFile = @"c:\DDMG\DXF_footer.txt";

            var start = DateTime.Now;

            string OUTFILE = @"c:\DDMG\SAMPLE.dxf";

            //delete if exists
            DeleteFileIfExists(OUTFILE);

            // Copy the header file and overwrite if it already exists
            File.Copy(sourceheaderFile, OUTFILE, true);

            Console.WriteLine($"WriteDXF: Writing dxf file '{OUTFILE}'..");

            int verticeswritten = 0;
            int polyswritten = 0;

            int startHexValue = 0xA0;  // Specify the starting hex value using an int
            int step = 1;  // How much to increment the hex value

            // Increment the hex value
            int nextHexValue = startHexValue + step;

            // Convert the incremented value back to a hex string
            string nextHexString = nextHexValue.ToString("X");

            using (StreamWriter myfile = new StreamWriter(OUTFILE, true))
            {
                for (int n = 0; n < MainImageBlock.PolyLineIncrementedCount; n++) 
                {
                    myfile.WriteLine("  0");
                    myfile.WriteLine("LWPOLYLINE");
                    myfile.WriteLine("  5");  // Leading spaces for 3-digit group codes
                    myfile.WriteLine(nextHexValue.ToString("X"));
                    myfile.WriteLine("100");
                    myfile.WriteLine("AcDbEntity");
                    myfile.WriteLine("  8");
                    myfile.WriteLine("0");
                    myfile.WriteLine("  6");
                    myfile.WriteLine("ByLayer");
                    myfile.WriteLine(" 62");
                    myfile.WriteLine("  256");
                    myfile.WriteLine("370");
                    myfile.WriteLine("   -1");
                    myfile.WriteLine("100");
                    myfile.WriteLine("AcDbPolyline");
                    myfile.WriteLine("90");
                    myfile.WriteLine("    " + MainImageBlock.Polylines[n].VertexCount);
                    myfile.WriteLine(" 70");
                    myfile.WriteLine("    0");
                    myfile.WriteLine(" 43"); //scale factor
                    myfile.WriteLine("0");

                    //copy over all vertices from this imageblock
                    for (int i = 0; i < MainImageBlock.Polylines[n].VertexCount; i++)
                    {
                        myfile.WriteLine(" 10");
                        myfile.WriteLine(MainImageBlock.Polylines[n].X[i]);
                        myfile.WriteLine(" 20");
                        myfile.WriteLine(MainImageBlock.Polylines[n].Y[i]);

                        verticeswritten++;
                    }

                    step++;
                    nextHexValue = startHexValue + step;

                    polyswritten++;
                }
            }

            // Read the contents of the source file
            byte[] footerContents = File.ReadAllBytes(sourcefooterFile);

            // Append the contents to the destination file
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(OUTFILE, FileMode.Append))
            {
                fs.Write(footerContents, 0, footerContents.Length);
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"WriteDXF: written {polyswritten} polys, {verticeswritten} vertices.");
            Console.WriteLine("WriteDXF: DXF creation complete!");
        }

